# Some Ember Data Fixtures Not Loaded

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having this really frustrating issue where some of my ember-data fixtures don't load their seed data.

This one loads its fixtures fine:

```
App.Place = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  products: DS.hasMany('App.Product'),
  logo_url: DS.attr('string')

App.Place.FIXTURES = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Whataburger', logo_url: "..."},
  {id: 2, name: 'Holiday Lanes', logo_url: "..."},
  {id: 3, name: 'IHOP', logo_url: "..."},
  {id: 4, name: 'Johnny\s Pizza House', logo_url: "..."},
  {id: 5, name: 'Chilli\'s', logo_url: "..."},
  {id: 6, name: 'Church\'s Chicken', logo_url: "..."},
  {id: 7, name: 'Starbucks', logo_url: "..."},
  {id: 8, name: 'Coldstone', logo_url: "..."},
  {id: 9, name: 'Strawns Eat Shop', logo_url: "..."}
]
```

This one does not load its fixtures:

```
App.Zoo = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  logo_url: DS.attr('string')

App.Zoo.FIXTURES = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Foo', logo_url: "..."}
]
```

What is the deal? I see the model in the chrome extension and all the fields are present, just not the records. I'm using the ember-source gem with version 1.0.0-rc.7. Ember data is version 0.13.

My store is defined like:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create()
```

My ZooRoute looks like:

```
App.ZooRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.Zoo.find()
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but did you define the Store for Fixture data? App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 13,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to a confusing combination of not defining a router initially (only for my example Zoo model) and not actually hitting that route (/#/zoos).

It turns out that Ember actually doesn't load fixtures into memory (only the model) until you execute a `find` on that model.

I can now hit the /#/zoos route and see the records loaded in the Ember Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

Your FIXTURES are loading just fine, I've created a working example out of the code you have provided: http://jsbin.com/odosoy/148/edit

There must be something else going on in your app that does not work, maybe in your `ZoosRoute` if you have one. Try to post more details on how you are loading the not working FIXTURES.

Hope it helps.